# How to filter the parent object by looping it's child array of object

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular-filters

I am getting some of objects from back-end. each of the object has the child array called 'phaseIds', it has multiple array of object, from the array i required to find the "name" existance according to the filter..

once i filtered, that object need to show in the page. I tried but i coun't get the result. any one help me with correct way to do this?

at present i am filter by students, but i am getting all the objects without filtered.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

var projects = [
    {"name":"one", "PhaseIds":[
      {id:"1",name:"school"},
      {id:"2",name:"student"},
      {id:"3",name:"teacher"}
      ]},
      {"name":"two", "PhaseIds":[
      {id:"1",name:"school"},
      {id:"3",name:"teacher"}
      ]},
      {"name":"three", "PhaseIds":[
      {id:"1",name:"school"},
      {id:"2",name:"student"}
      ]},
      {"name":"four", "PhaseIds":[
      {id:"1",name:"school"},
      {id:"3",name:"teacher"}
      ]},
      {"name":"five", "PhaseIds":[
      {id:"1",name:"school"},
      {id:"3",name:"teacher"}
      ]}
  ]

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.projects = angular.forEach( projects, function (project) {
    
   var filteredProject = project;
   
   angular.forEach( project.PhaseIds, function ( phase ) {
     
    if(phase.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('student') > -1 ){ 
      //only required the students avilable projects
      
        return filteredProject;
      
    }
      
   })
    
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="project in projects">{{project.name}}</li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mrXYeebY9JJeFpsuSJMv?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needn't put the logic in your controller code. You can achieve it in your HTML snippet as well by using `$filter`. Check below example. You can make your filter structure as deeper as you want.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:{ PhaseIds : { name : 'student' } }">{{project.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Please check your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NnHCvWLc1yOBsBanHj8o?p=preview). I've updated it

Comment: for the static purpose may be this work out. but I am looking for dynamic update. my case there is no.of buttons for each 'student' 'teacher' like so.. according to the user click (filter button) i need to show different projects

Comment: You can achieve the same in above snippet :-)

Comment: Hey vineet I tried your solution.. For me when I tried in JSFIDDLE it did not work can you please check what I am doing wrong..
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/varun1989/w9qyqjz7/1/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the @Vineet solution but if you need to play with the Json from the controller the right code should be:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.projects = [];
    angular.forEach(projects, function (project) {

        var filteredProject = project;

        angular.forEach(project.PhaseIds, function (phase) {
            if (phase.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('student') > -1) {
                //only required the students avilable projects
                $scope.projects.push(filteredProject);
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.projects = [];
  angular.forEach( projects, function (project) {

   var filteredProject = project;

   angular.forEach( project.PhaseIds, function ( phase ) {

    if(phase.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('student') > -1 ){ 
      //only required the students avilable projects

       $scope.projects = $scope.projects.concat(filteredProject)    
    }

   })

  })

});
```

Hre is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S93HoAkfR7VjgmTyJ90I?p=preview)

EDIT :

using concat you will get object structure like this as per your requirement.

```
[   {"name":"one", "PhaseIds":[
      {id:"1",name:"school"},
      {id:"2",name:"student"},
      {id:"3",name:"teacher"}
      ]},

      {"name":"three", "PhaseIds":[
      {id:"1",name:"school"},
      {id:"2",name:"student"}
      ]}       
  ]
```

And using push you will get like this

```
[0: [{
    "name": "one",
    "PhaseIds": [{
        id: "1",
        name: "school"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "student"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "teacher"
    }]
}],
1: [{
    "name": "three",
    "PhaseIds": [{
        id: "1",
        name: "school"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "student"
    }]
}]]
```

Comment: why `concat` instead of `push` - any special reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the solution here - http://plnkr.co/edit/seIfZlhIbUnYMhWdEpGr

```
var filterProjectData = function(projects) {

   var filteredProjects = []; 

  angular.forEach( projects, function (project) {

   angular.forEach( project.PhaseIds, function ( phase ) {

    if(phase.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('student') > -1 ){ 
      //only required the students avilable projects

        filteredProjects.push(project);
    }

   });

  });

  return filteredProjects;
}

$scope.projects = filterProjectData(projects);
```

No brainier . I simply tweaked your foreach logic.